# Running NavigOwl plugin for Protégé

Tags: plugins, ontology, protege

I'm working on a semantic-web project and I'm looking for real-life ontologies to test a couple of applications an algorithms. What I'm searching for are different sizes and structures, something that will allow me to benchmark the company's solutions, preferably, not home-made mocks, but something that is actually used. Unfortunately, looking at the entire ontology using OntoGraf is a little cumbersome.

I found a Protégé plugin called NavigOwl, which seems to be perfect for the task of viewing an entire ontology at once and judging its general complication and structure. The thing is, I can't get it to work.

I download the plugin from [HERE](http://klatif.seecs.nust.edu.pk/navigowl/downloads.html) and follow the instructions.

- I put the jar in the `plugin` directory of my Protégé install.
- I open protege and load an ontology
- I go to `Window>Tabs` and select `NavigOwl`
- A NavigOwl tab appears but it only contains the class hierarchy view, while the rest of the window is grey. It's simply blank, as shown below:

[image: blank NavigOwl tab in Protégé]

Clicking any of the classes in the hierarchy view does not change anything.

I googled for a solution and I managed to find this [thread on nabble.com](http://protege-ontology-editor-knowledge-acquisition-system.136.n4.nabble.com/A-quick-question-about-Views-td3742373.html). The poster says he fixed the problem but he doesn't know how. Resetting the tab to default state is among the implied solutions but it doesn't work for me. Closing and reopening the tab, as well as Protégé itself changes nothing.

Have you encountered the problem? What could be the cause?

I'm using Protégé 4.1.0 Build 239 with the bundled JRE (1.5.0) on Windows 7 home premium x64.

I've tried both the JAR available [here (NavigOwl plugin for Protégé 4.1)](http://klatif.seecs.nust.edu.pk/navigowl/downloads.html) and the one mentioned in Protégé wiki at Stanford, [here (version 1.1.0)](http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/NavigOWL_1.1.0) but the situation persists.

Answer (score 1):

I had came across the same problem but when i upgraded the JDK it started working. though i do not propose upgrading was the solution but it is working now.
[image: screenshot of navigOWL working with latest Protégé 4.3]

Comment: Thanks. I've actually switched jobs in the meantime and I no longer use it but I'll check this out of curiosity. Which version did you have that was causing problems and which upgrade may have resolved this?

Comment: I was using 4.2 when it was giving problem but i can not confirm that it was the older version that was causing it to hang and then get crashed.